# Kubernetes 1.5.2 ping can't find ClusterIP of a Service from inside Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a Cluster with some deployments and services.

I can log into any of my pods and ping the pods from their pod network ips ( 172.x.x.x ) and they are successful.

But when I try to ping the services ClusterIP addresses from any of my pods they never respond, so I can't access my services.

Below is my Kibana deployment, and 10.254.77.135 is the IP I am trying to connect to from my other services, I also can't use this node port, it never responds

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kibana",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kibana",
    "uid": "21498caf-569c-11e7-a801-0050568fc023",
    "resourceVersion": "3282683",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-06-21T16:10:23Z",
    "labels": {
      "component": "elk",
      "role": "kibana"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "http",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 5601,
        "targetPort": 5601,
        "nodePort": 31671
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "kibana"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.254.77.135",
    "type": "NodePort",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: did you mean "I _can_ log into any of my pods"

Comment: Which setup guide, or instructions did you follow to setup your cluster? 
 What type of networking support are you using (see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-achieve-this)

Comment: Correct it's CAN

Comment: I am using flannel and the "pod" network (correct me if this makes no sense) works, but the services are just not "findable" over the 10.254.x.x sub net

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but apparently `ping` doesn't work on services ClusterIP addresses because they are virtual addresses created by iptables rules that just redirect packets to the endpoints(pods).